# How to explode a war file in buildr

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war, buildr

I'm new to buildr, so I might be missing something obvious.

According to [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BUILDR/How+to+explode+a+.war+file), it should be fairly simple:

> 1. Download [explode.rb](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/114869/explode.rb?version=2&modificationDate=1244900095000)
> 2. At the top of your buildfile, add the following:
>
>    `require 'explode.rb'`
> 3. Define explode task on your web application:
>
>    `package(:war).explode :target => "jetty/webapps/myApplication"`
> 4. Run the task
>
>    `buildr myApp:explode`

However, but I can't get it to work. If I just go through the steps in that article, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError : Don't know how to build task 'myApp:explode'
```

I tried all sorts of combinations, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the instructions were 100% correct. My problem was that `myApp` was a sub-project, and I needed the fully qualified name when running the task, i.e.:

```
buildr myProject:myApp:explode
```

I was confused because just running `buildr myApp` worked fine.